# How to disable blue pin while adding a MapOverlay to Map on Heremaps API (Android)

Tags: android, here-api

I'm trying to Add a MapOverlay the map on LongPressEvent, and after this center the map, but even without centering the map, it always shows a blue pin(heremaps default pin) before showing the overlay.

Is there any way to prevent showing the blue pin while adding a MapOverlay?

UPDATE with more code:

Coordinates

```
private class MapGestureListener implements MapGesture.OnGestureListener{
...
        @Override
        public boolean onLongPressEvent(PointF pointF) {
            GeoCoordinate gc =map.pixelToGeo(pointF);
            if(sdkMapSettingsListener!=null)
                sdkMapSettingsListener.onLongPress(gc);
            return false; //i've tried returning true and then use map.setCenter and the problem persists.
}

...

then on my listener:

        @Override
        public void onLongPress(GeoCoordinate gc) {
        if(mo!=null)
        {

            map.removeMapOverlay(mo);
            mo=null;
        }//remove old overlay if exists

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_map_info_window, null);
        RelativeLayout info_window_wrapper = view.findViewById(R.id.info_window_wrapper);
        info_window_wrapper.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(ThemeUtils.getEntityColor(GPSApplication.getInstance(),Constants.EntityTheme.colorPrimary)));
        ImageView imgPlaceIcon = view.findViewById(R.id.imageView_placeIcon);
        imgPlaceIcon.setColorFilter(ThemeUtils.getEntityColor(GPSApplication.getInstance(),Constants.EntityTheme.colorAccent));
        ImageView ivPlaceMarker = view.findViewById(R.id.ivPlaceMarker);
        ivPlaceMarker.setColorFilter(ThemeUtils.getEntityColor(GPSApplication.getInstance(),Constants.EntityTheme.colorAccent));

        TextView textViewPlaceName = view.findViewById(R.id.textView_PlaceName);
        final TextView textViewOpenNow = view.findViewById(R.id.textView_OpenNow);
        TextView textViewDistance = view.findViewById(R.id.textView_Distance);

        textViewPlaceName.setTextColor(ThemeUtils.getEntityColor(GPSApplication.getInstance(),Constants.EntityTheme.primaryTextColor));
        textViewDistance.setTextColor(ThemeUtils.getEntityColor(GPSApplication.getInstance(),Constants.EntityTheme.primaryTextColor));
     String sDistance = SearchManager.getInstance().requestDistanceTo(gc,mContext);
        textViewPlaceName.setText(sPlace);
        textViewDistance.setText(sDistance);

        mo = new MapOverlay(view,gc);
        mo.setAnchorPoint(new PointF(ScreenUtils.convertDPToPixels(mContext,75),ScreenUtils.convertDPToPixels(mContext,108)));
        map.addMapOverlay(mo);
        //map.setCenter(gc, Map.Animation.LINEAR);

}
```

MapOverlay view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/info_window_wrapper"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="69dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin_xsmall"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/margin_xsmall"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/margin_xsmall"
        android:paddingBottom="25dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_info_window_shape"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_PlaceName"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:text=""/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/textView_PlaceName">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_OpenNow"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:text="Open" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView_placeIcon"
                android:layout_width="17dp"
                android:layout_height="17dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textView_Distance"
                android:padding="@dimen/margin_xxsmall"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_place_white_24dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_Distance"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:text=""
                android:textSize="12sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivPlaceMarker"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_place_white_24dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.47"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/info_window_wrapper" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[The first screen is what is shows first (The blue pin), then the second screen (the MapOverlay)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKQ3Z.png)

UPDATE video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qNuZNUWDxeQ

UPDATE 2 sample activity similar to our project, where this problem happens and there's no marker added:

```
public class TheThirdActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final static int REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS = 1;

    /**
     * Permissions that need to be explicitly requested from end user.
     */
    private static final String[] REQUIRED_SDK_PERMISSIONS = new String[] {
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE };
    private Map map = null;
    private SupportMapFragment mapFragment = null;
    MapOverlay mo;
    Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater inflater;


    SDKMapSettingsListener sdkMapSettingsListener;
    public interface SDKMapSettingsListener {
        void onLongPress(GeoCoordinate gc);
    }

    public void setSdkMapSettingsListener(SDKMapSettingsListener listener) {
        this.sdkMapSettingsListener = listener;
    }

    private SupportMapFragment getMapFragment() {
        return (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapfragment);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mContext = this;
        inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_the_third);
        mapFragment = getMapFragment();
        boolean success = com.here.android.mpa.common.MapSettings.setIsolatedDiskCacheRootPath(
                getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir(null) + File.separator + ".here-maps",
                "com.here.android.tutorial.MapService");

        if (!success) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to set isolated disk cache path.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        } else {
            mapFragment.init(new OnEngineInitListener() {
                @Override
                public void onEngineInitializationCompleted(OnEngineInitListener.Error error) {
                    if (error == OnEngineInitListener.Error.NONE) {
                        map = mapFragment.getMap();
                        map.setCenter(new GeoCoordinate(41.160465,-8.647859 ), Map.Animation.NONE);
                        map.setZoomLevel(18);

                        map.setMapScheme(Map.Scheme.NORMAL_TRAFFIC_NIGHT);
                        mapFragment.getMapGesture().addOnGestureListener(new MapGesture.OnGestureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean onLongPressEvent(PointF pointF) {
                                GeoCoordinate gc =map.pixelToGeo(pointF);
                                if(sdkMapSettingsListener!=null)
                                    sdkMapSettingsListener.onLongPress(gc);
                                return true;
                            }
                            @Override
                            public boolean onTapEvent(PointF pointF) {
                                if(mo!=null)
                                    map.removeMapOverlay(mo);
                                mo=null;
                                return false;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onPanStart() {

                            }
                            @Override
                            public void onPanEnd() {

                            }
                            @Override
                            public void onMultiFingerManipulationStart() {

                            }
                            @Override
                            public void onMultiFingerManipulationEnd() {

                            }
                            @Override
                            public boolean onMapObjectsSelected(List<ViewObject> list) {
                                return false;
                            }
                            @Override
                            public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(PointF pointF) {
                                return false;
                            }
                            @Override
                            public void onPinchLocked() {

                            }
                            @Override
                            public boolean onPinchZoomEvent(float v, PointF pointF) {
                                return false;
                            }
                            @Override
                            public void onRotateLocked() {

                            }
                            @Override
                            public boolean onRotateEvent(float v) {
                                return false;
                            }
                            @Override
                            public boolean onTiltEvent(float v) {
                                return false;
                            }
                            @Override
                            public void onLongPressRelease() {

                            }
                            @Override
                            public boolean onTwoFingerTapEvent(PointF pointF) {
                                return false;
                            }
                        }, 1, true);
                        sdkMapSettingsListener = new SDKMapSettingsListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onLongPress(GeoCoordinate gc) {
                                if(mo!=null)
                                {

                                    map.removeMapOverlay(mo);
                                    mo=null;
                                }

                                View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_map_info_window, null);
                                RelativeLayout info_window_wrapper = view.findViewById(R.id.info_window_wrapper);
                                info_window_wrapper.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.BLACK));
                                ImageView imgPlaceIcon = view.findViewById(R.id.imageView_placeIcon);
                                imgPlaceIcon.setColorFilter(Color.YELLOW);
                                ImageView ivPlaceMarker = view.findViewById(R.id.ivPlaceMarker);
                                ivPlaceMarker.setColorFilter(Color.YELLOW);

                                TextView textViewPlaceName = view.findViewById(R.id.textView_PlaceName);
                                final TextView textViewOpenNow = view.findViewById(R.id.textView_OpenNow);
                                TextView textViewDistance = view.findViewById(R.id.textView_Distance);

                                textViewPlaceName.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                                textViewDistance.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                                String sDistance = requestDistanceTo(gc,mContext);
                                textViewPlaceName.setText("sample place");
                                textViewDistance.setText(sDistance);

                                mo = new MapOverlay(view,gc);
                                mo.setAnchorPoint(new PointF(convertDPToPixels(mContext,75),convertDPToPixels(mContext,108)));
                                map.addMapOverlay(mo);
                                map.setCenter(gc, Map.Animation.LINEAR);
                            }
                        };
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("ERROR: Cannot initialize Map Fragment");
                    }


                }
            });
        }
    }

    public int convertDPToPixels(Context context, int dip) {
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dip, displayMetrics);
    }

    public String requestDistanceTo(@NonNull GeoCoordinate geoCoordinate, @NonNull Context mContext)
    {
        String sFinal="";
        double dDist=0;
        if(PositioningManager.getInstance().getPosition().getCoordinate().isValid())
        {
            dDist= PositioningManager.getInstance().getPosition().getCoordinate().distanceTo(geoCoordinate);
        }
        else
        {
            if(PositioningManager.getInstance().getLastKnownPosition().getCoordinate().isValid())
                dDist= PositioningManager.getInstance().getLastKnownPosition().getCoordinate().distanceTo(geoCoordinate);
            else
                return "";
        }
        long lDist = (long) dDist;
        sFinal= formatInMetricSystem(mContext,lDist);
        return sFinal;
    }

    private static final NumberFormat FORMATTER = NumberFormat.getInstance();
    public static String formatInMetricSystem(final Context context, final long distance) {
        final String value;
        final String unit;
        if (distance < 0) { // invalid
            value = "--";
            unit = "m";
        } else if (distance < 1000) {
            value = FORMATTER.format(distance);
            unit = "m";
        } else {
            value = FORMATTER.format(Math.round((double) distance / 1000));
            unit = "km";
        }
        return String.format("%1$s%2$s", value, unit);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show a little more code (e.g center of map, the overlay view and the overlay coordinates) and a screenshot please.

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport thank for your reply, updated with the requested info.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your first screenshot, the only way the MapMarker (pin) can show on the map is if you are adding it somewhere in your code.  From the second screenshot, it looks like the MapOverlay is just covering the MapMarker (pin). Can you please check your code to see if you are adding a MapMarker to the map and remove it (`map.removeMapObject(<map marker>)`.

Comment: i double checked it, i'm only using customized MapMarkers after route calculation, this process is used before route calculation. i'll attach a video.

Comment: Added a sample activity where this problem persists and there's no mapmarker added. @HEREDeveloperSupport